# neo4j apoc merge nodes to one specific node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In our graph we have some nodes of persons which are connected with SAME_AS-edges, because they all mean the same person.

[image]

[image]

One of the nodes, with the name-property starting with a major character and a number is the main node, to which all others should be merges to.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jerome said, you should use `APOC` to do that, with the `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes` procedure.

But it's true that you can be exposed to an error if :

- your nodes are not looked up with an index
- or, if you don't have an eager phase (for your nodes)  in the execution plan before the call of the procedure.

So to solve this you can do something like that :

```
MATCH (n1:Person {name:$name1}),
      (n2:Person {name:$name2}),
      (n3:Person {name:$name3}),
      (n4:Person {name:$name4})
WITH head( collect( [n1, n2, n3, n4] ) ) AS nodes
  CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes)  YIELD node 
  RETURN node
```

Comment: Thanks for the query but the number of nodes to merge are variabel (i think from 2-5 nodes) and we have about 40.000 nodes connected with same_as-edges in the graph. I just added another picture to the question. Which query works for that ?

Comment: Thank you Benoit for this tip

Comment: My query is just an example. The principal part is the `collect` function that will produce the eager aggregation on your nodes, and so allow you to use the apoc merge procedure.